# How can an Ember.js {{#link-to}} become active when the URL updates in an eager transition?

Tags: ember.js

Using Loading Substates, I've opted into [eager transitions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_eager-vs-lazy-async-transitions) between my routes. This causes the URL to immediately update when a link to a route with a slow-to-resolve promise is clicked. However, the `{{#link-to}}` helper doesn't get its `active` class until after the model hook's promise has resolved and the transition has completed.

Is there a way to make the `{{#link-to}}`s become active automatically whenever the URL changes and the loading route is shown? Here's an example JSBin: http://output.jsbin.com/pokujo#/about

Comment: If you create an ArrayProxy first (in the model hook) -then fire off the XHR that when resolved populates the proxy. But don't wait for it to resolve before returning -instead return the empty array right away. When the XHR resolves you will see the view render the "new" items (via 2WDB). Here is a full blown example (ember-cli) app https://github.com/toranb/async-kanban-board-store-example

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention ember-data ... you could do this like so (w/ a little help from [ember-cli-simple-store](https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store))

your model hook will not wait for the promise to resolve :)

```
model: function() {
    var store = this.get("store");
    var all = store.find("todo");
    PromiseMixin.xhr("/api/todos").then(function(response) {
        response.forEach(function(data) {
            store.push("todo", data);
        });
    });
    return all;
}
```